# Query for selecting particular string from a larger string in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a column value as below 'INDIA#PRODUCT1#,CANADA#PRODUCT1#,USA#PRODUCT3,CANADA#PRODUCT1#,EMEA#PRODUCT2,USA#PRODUCT4#,ITALY#PRODUCT2#,EMEA#PRODUCT2#'

Now want a select query in oracle 10g which gives me the output as two columns Product1 and product2 as below

```
PRODUCT1
```

INDIA,CANADA,CANADA

```
PRODUCT2
```

EMEA,ITALY,EMEA

All regions which has product1 as one column and regions which has product2 as another column as comma separated values.
Note: should not use pivot concept as it is 10g and should not create any function which can be used in the select clause to achieve this output. This needs to be achieved is a select query itself, please help

Thanks

Comment: Wow, terrible database design if you have to do something like this.  look at regular expressions as a possible option.  Why the opposition to writing a function?

Comment: working in a banking domain at L2 level support, so don't have privilege to create functions. This requirement is for a report generation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some nasty example of retrieving such data in 2 columns PRODUCT - CONUTRIES:

```
WITH items AS
(SELECT TRIM('#' FROM TRIM(SUBSTR(MYTEXT, INSTR (MYTEXT, ',', 1, level) + 1, INSTR (MYTEXT, ',', 1, level+1) - INSTR (MYTEXT, ',', 1, level) -1 ))) AS item
  FROM
    ( SELECT ',' || 'INDIA#PRODUCT1#,CANADA#PRODUCT1#,USA#PRODUCT3,CANADA#PRODUCT1#,EMEA#PRODUCT2,USA#PRODUCT4#,ITALY#PRODUCT2#,EMEA#PRODUCT2' ||',' AS MYTEXT FROM dual
    )
    CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(MYTEXT)-LENGTH(REPLACE(MYTEXT,',',''))-1
)
,products AS
(
  SELECT
    'PRODUCT'||LEVEL AS product
    ,'\w+#PRODUCT'||LEVEL AS product_regex
  FROM
    dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5
)
SELECT
  p.product
  ,TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.item,'^[^#]+')||',') ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.item,'^[^#]+')).EXTRACT('//text()')
  ) AS countries
FROM
  items i
  ,products p
WHERE
  REGEXP_LIKE(i.item,p.product_regex)
GROUP BY
  p.product;
```

This gives the following result:

```
PRODUCT    |    COUNTRY
-----------------------------------
PRODUCT1   |  CANADA,CANADA,INDIA
PRODUCT2   |  EMEA,EMEA,ITALY
PRODUCT3   |  USA
PRODUCT4   |  USA
```

Will try to sort out something a bit closer to your solution later.
Hope this little snippet will help you a bit.